# R - Run source() in background

Tags: r, background

I want to execute a R script in the background from the R console.

From the console , i usually run R script as source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
I have to wait until the script is completed to go ahead with my rest of work.
Instead of this i want R to be running in the background  while i can continue with my work in the console.
Also i should be somehow notified when R completes the source command.
Is this possible in R ?

This might be quite useful as we often sees jobs taking long time.

PS - i want the source script to be running in the same memory space rather than  a new one. Hence solutions like fork , system etc wont work for me. I am seeing if i can run the R script as a separate thread and not a separate process.

Comment: The question here is:  do you need the output of your script "now," or "later" ?  If it's not needed for the work you're doing, then run the script later.  If the work you're doing depends on the output, then you have to wait until it's done anyway.  If it's a completely separate task, then run it in its own instance of R and let your OS (or hypervisor, or equivalent) do the memory swapping.

Comment: Do i need the output now - YES , but i dont want to wait until its done , i might as well submit other jobs in between. 
Why i cant run it as a seprate R instance - cause there is some stuffs loaded into the main memory which i dont want to load again.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `system()` and Rscript to run your script as an asynchronous background process:

```
system("Rscript -e 'source(\"your-script.R\")'", wait=FALSE)
```

At the end of your script, you may save your objects with `save.image()` in order to load them later, and notify of its completion with `cat()`:

```
...
save.image("script-output.RData")
cat("Script completed\n\n")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks good but doesn’t this use another memory space ? If so , it is not a solution for me. I want the source to run as a thread and not a separate process as there are many data loaded into the main memory that the function needs to access.

Comment: R is single-threaded. If you want, Revolution Analytics (www.revolutionanalytics.com) has a commercial multi-threaded version of R. But are you sure you need it? I mean your script can itself load the data it needs, and I would guess you only need to work with the final output of the script, not with any intermediate output.

Comment: As R is made in C++ , i beleive R should be able to support multi threading may be through any of its packages.

Comment: To add to this , i believe what package is offering is essentially multi threading but based on cores rather than time slices.

Comment: R is written in C, plus some Fortran. And I don't think multi-threading can be implemented at the package level. Anyway, your question was about parallelizing a task, and I see no reason why you couldn't use separate R processes for that. Input/output for each sub-task needs to be synchronized anyway, and you can use `save.image()` and `load()` to send input to and get output from each R process. I do it all the time...

Comment: I am loading tons of data to the main memory of the R instance am using. And the script is using these data to process. So forking means i will have to replicate the whole main memory which hinters the performance which is not possible for me.

Comment: How does signaling the completion of the background process work exactly? `cat` writes to stdout which is not captured in an R variable if you use `wait=FALSE`

Comment: If you're passing a system command to run a script. You only need `Rscript the_script.R` source is not required.

Comment: For convenience, you can wrap this in a function similar to `source()`, so that you can easily run R processes on background just like with `source()`, but also saving a log file on the same directory as your script:

`source_bg <- function(file) {
  log <- stringr::str_remove(file, "\\w+$") |> paste0("log")
  system(glue::glue("Rscript '{file}' >> '{log}' 2>&1"), wait = F)
}`