# Run asynchronous function in R

Tags: r, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
myfun <- function() {
  fun2()

  return(1+1)
}
```

I want fun2() is invoked and then moved to the next lines without waiting for the result. Function fun2 does not return anything and I don't care when it finishes, I just need to launch it. What is the best way to achieve it? Parallel process, multithreading, async call? Any code samples are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Run source() in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208976/r-run-source-in-background)

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows?

Comment: Yes, windows 7. Though I want to have it working also on other OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I stopped on the following solution:

```
Rpath <- Find(file.exists, c(commandArgs()[[1]], file.path(R.home("bin"), commandArgs()[[1]]),
                             file.path(R.home("bin"), "R"), file.path(R.home("bin"), "Rscript.exe")))
out <- system('%s --no-save --slave -e \"Your R code here\" ', wait=FALSE)
```

The first line searches for the path of R executable, and the second executes R code from the command-line environment not waiting for result.

Answer (score 25):

The [future package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) (I'm the author) provides this:

```
library("future")
plan(multisession)

myfun <- function() {
  future(fun2())

  return(1+1)
}
```

Unless `fun2()` is function used purely for its side effects, you typically want to retrieve the value of that future expression, which you do as:

```
f <- future(fun2())
y <- fun3()
v <- value(f)
z <- v + y
```

An alternative is to use the `%<-%` operator, as in:

```
v %<-% fun2()
y <- fun3()
z <- v + y
```

FYI, if you use

```
plan(cluster, workers = c("n1", "n3", "remote.server.org"))
```

then the future expression is resolved on one of those machines.  Using

```
plan(future.batchtools::batchtools_slurm)
```

will cause it to be resolved via a Slurm job scheduler queue.

Comment: Would you recommend the `foreach` interface for using the future engine, or `furrr`?

Comment: They're all map-reduce siblings and equally efficient when it comes to parallel processing: [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach) w/ [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doFuture), [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply), [furrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/furrr), ... You can pick the map-reduce style you like.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your rstudio presentation, thank you for helping us run our models faster!

Comment: Thanks and I'm glad you find it useful. {future} is building on-top of prior and existing work by others, so I'm standing on giants

Comment: I think that's the best way on async code. One thing attention: in multisession plan, we should remember to init some context inside the function that be asynced. Such as, if the function (which will give to the future) will run `somedb.sql(...)`, a `somedb.init(tokenfile)` might need to write inside that function also, or it will err such as "need a somedb.init at first".